# Solving Rules of Inference problem with Indirect Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So I have been given the following question and premises:-

**Task:** Proof the above premises and hypothesis using Indirect proof

**Premise 1: $P \rightarrow \neg R$**

**Premise 2: $Q \rightarrow S$**

**Premise 3: $(R \vee S) \rightarrow T$**

**Premise 4: $\neg T$**

**Hypothesis: $P \vee Q$**

The above seems like normal a Rules of Inference problem, but the thing that bugging me was that it asks for **Indirect proof**.

Inside my logic note that was given by my teacher, there was no method taught in order to solve this kind of ROI question using the Indirect proof method. The only Indirect method taught was to solve for some mathematical proof (such as even (2K) & odd problem (2K+1)), but not for the kind above. I don't even know how to approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: I have edited premise 1, I inserted the wrong premise before.

Comment: You cannot prove it.

Comment: After the edit of premise 1, it's still wrong: if $P, Q, R, S, T$ are all false, the premises are all true, but $P \lor Q$ is not.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Then by that, I've been given a wrong question by my teacher, please take a look at this snapped picture from whom I deduced the above premises: https://i.imgur.com/2G4pvE4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

An indirect proof is the same as a proof by contradiction. So: you need to assume $\neg(P \lor Q)$, and show that that leads to a contradiction.

.. which shouldn't be hard: $\neg(P \lor Q)$ means $\neg P$, so with Premise 1 you get $R$, so $R\lor S$, and so with Premise 3 you get T, which contradicts Premise 4 $\neg T$.  The formal details will depend on the exact nature of your proof system.

EDIT

After you changed Premise 1, the argument is no longer valid! If $P,Q,R,S,T$ are all false, then all premises are true, but the conclusion is false.

Comment: From what I've been taught in class, for indirect proof (not for above kind of question though) we've to use proof by contrapositive. Is proof by contradiction is also a kind of indirect proof? Sorry for the lack of my knowledge.

Comment: @MohdShahril A proof by contrapositive is typically when you have to prove a conditional like $P \rightarrow Q$ by showing that $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$.  But in this case you are not trying to prove a conditional. So you really need a proof by contradiction: assume the opposite of what you need to prove, and show how that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: There was a mistake, for premise 1 which I edited to correct the statement back.

Comment: By the way, can you show me the steps to proof it using contradiction? I seem can't proof it even with your clue. :(

Comment: @MohdShahril I will need to know the rules of your proof system.

Comment: @MohdShahril Wait! I just saw your correction!  Eh, that correction actually makes the argument invalid ... are you sure you have all the correct statements?

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand what did you mean by "rules of proof system". However, here is the original photo of the question, from which I extracted the premises above using information from this photo: https://i.imgur.com/2G4pvE4.png

Comment: @MohdShahril Sorry, crazy busy, can;t really chat.  But when it says 'rules of inference', they must refer to a certain set of rules, because there are many different sets of rules of inference.  But more importantly: that argument is invalid!! You can't prove it!